# Difference between being signed in on incognito and being signed in on chrome

Tags: google-chrome

If I am signed in on a window on incognito, how is it different from being signed in from a regular chrome tab?

Does everything you view stay? For example, I looked up about facts about President Trump, but will my admin be able to wee I searched that even if I am not on the same network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that the chrome will not save some information about your activity like it does in normal mode.

In Incognito mode it won't save your history, download history, bookmarks, passwords and autofillsand it will delete all cookies after the end of the incognito session.

It is all only about the Chrome storing the information. Other sources will be normally able to see the web trafic - that means your internet provider, your employer, etc...

If your admin watches only the browser history, you are safe. But there are A LOT OF other and better means to monitor the web trafic on a specific network. If you were on a network your admin cannot monitor - you are safe too.